# Will my SEO be hurt by using a "/" to seperate two different ways of reffering to the same thing?

Tags: seo

I am building a site that lets people Trade, Buy and Sell Magic the Gathering cards ( a collectable card game) and I'm struggling to fit my main Index pages Title in a manner that will not get concatenated in the results view.

So generally the Magic the Gathering name is shortened to "MTG" and I want to use both of those keywords in my title.

If I go with a title of:

**Trade, Buy & Sell Magic The Gathering/MTG Cards |MTG PeerTrader**

will I be hurting myself in the conjoining of the "Gathering/MTG" keywords?

I started out with:

**Trade, Buy & Sell Magic The Gathering / MTG Cards | MTG PeerTrader**

but it is just too long :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is it too long? It's the exact same number of letters.

Comment: The 2nd has spaces in it where I have removed some of them in the first to try and get the whole name into the search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the spaces around the slash are needed.  It doesn't look odd to me personally, and the slash can separate words to Google's algorithms.   The lack of space after the pipe does look odd to me, but Googles's algorithms shouldn't have any problem with it.

I would not recommend repeating any keywords in the title.  You have "MTG" in your brand name, so I wouldn't try to target that keyword a second time.  How about:

```
Trade, Buy & Sell Magic The Gathering Cards | MTG PeerTrader
```

On the home page, I would recommend putting the Brand name at the front:

```
MTG PeerTrader: Trade, Buy & Sell Magic The Gathering Cards
```

On other pages, I would recommend the brand name go at the end.

I would also consider removing "Trade, Buy & Sell" from the page title and putting them exclusively in the meta description.

```
MTG PeerTrader: Magic the Gathering Cards
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, not having MTG twice makes sense, everything I read on SEO suggested that the title is the important part to have the keywords the site is focused around.

Comment: I'm thinking for my home page: MTG PeerTrader | Trade, Buy & Sell Magic The Gathering Cards

Comment: A descriptive title beats a keyword loaded title.  Thats good for the homepage but try to adapt it a little for the rest so that it matches the page content or at least the section of the site.

Comment: @JamesRyan I was planning on something like `Search for Magic The Gathering / MTG Cards | MTG PeerTrader` for the "Search" page, though Stephen brings up a good point and I might change to just `Search for Magic The Gathering Cards | MTG PeerTrader` to avoid duplicating keywords.  Please use the `@` if you reply so I get a notification.

Comment: @Mark no one would search for 'search x' though would they?

Comment: @JamesRyan Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: @Mark using search as a keyword is pointless because the person is already searching google or whatever.  'Find' might be more helpful

Comment: @JamesRyan Ah, I understand your point now, and I get it.  The title would come from the name of the page, but I'll check around to see what other sites in the space would do.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend for the seperation between two words by comma. All the descpription, keywords writes on comma format. Eg. SEO, link building, traffic, web traffic. All keywords seperated by comma.